# Is there a way to purge a DTC transaction from command line?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2019, distributed-transactions, msdtc

as you can see on my screenshot, I have a DTC transaction in error on my server.

I know, I can Right -> Resolve -> Forget/Abort

However, I want to do it with a command line (batch or Powershell). Is there any way to do that?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Is the DTC enlisted with SQL Server ? If so you can use Transact SQL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msdtc/set-dtctransaction?view=windowsserver2019-ps